# square-connect API Desktop Application integration

Tags: desktop, square-connect

I'm developing a Desktop Application using Qt C++ Framework.

I've plans to add direct payment facility from my application.

Is there any possibilities of accepting Credit Card details on my Dialog controls and communicate with Square-connect api to process the payment?

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently support using our API from a native application at this time.